# Question about changing university policy

Tags: discussion

As it currently stands [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23897/challenge-the-caste-based-reservation-policy-system-in-supreme-court) is off topic and not a good fit for our site since it is mainly about legal issues. That said, it sounds like the Indian university system has some issues. I think a great question for us would be one that focuses on how to go about changing a fundamental university policy that is controversial.

Does anyone else think this question is salvageable?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that particular question is salvageable for this site. However, how to challenge an unfair institutional policy from *within* would be a reasonable question for this community.

Answer (score 2):

I think one way to salvage the question is to ask how other universities have dealt with similar situations. Answers might comment on the history of affirmative action programs in the U.S., intended to redress the lack of minorities in higher education.